# Am I abusing useEffect()? - Filtering data based on updated query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

Basically, I wanted to filter some data when a user clicks on checkboxes. The query will update and upon refresh, the filtered data is still there. I have two components, ShopPlants which is where the data will be displayed as well as filtering the data based on the query.  ShopNavPlants is where the query will be updated and handle any active filtering states. Everything is working fine, but my code seems to be a bit sloppy and I need some guidance if I am overcomplicating myself or if my solution is just bad practice in general.

In terms of my solution, I created two components and keeping tabs with the router using useRouter from Next. ShopPlants that checks for query updates and filters accordingly once router.IsReady is true with router.isReady and router.,query as dependencies. In ShopNav, I have two useEffects, one which pushes a new query based on fitlerState changes (there's also a debounce timer I added to prevent an abundance of URL changes). The other useEffect in ShopNav handles any refreshes or re-renders of the whole page by pushing any active queries to the filterState. The only reason I needed this is because router.query returns undefined on the first render which is my reasoning for using router.isReady in my useEffect.

ShopPlants:

```
const ShopPlants = (props) => {
  // State handles current display of products
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(
    sortProducts(props.products, "featured")
  );
  const router = useRouter();

  // Handles sorting and updates display
  const sortHandler = (curSort) => {
    const sortedProducts = sortProducts(products, curSort);
    setProducts(sortedProducts);
  };

  // Handles filtering data based on query changes
  useEffect(() => {
    // FILTER HERE
    if (router.isReady) {
      // checks if query 'features' for filtering exists to filter accordingly
      if (router.query?.features) {
        // convert query to an array and return filteredItems
        const toArray = router.query.features.split("&");
        const filteredItems = props.products.filter((product) => {
          const bool = toArray.map((fitlerName) => product[fitlerName]);
          return bool.every((item) => item);
        });

        // set current products display to filtered data
        setProducts(sortProducts(filteredItems, "featured"));
        return;
      }

      // if no filter query is found, return default
      setProducts(sortProducts(props.products, "featured"));
    }
  }, [router.isReady, router.query]);

  return (
    <section className="shop">
      <div className="shop__container section-container">
        <div className="shop__heading">
          <h1 className="heading-secondary">Shop Plants</h1>
          <ShopSort sortedHandler={sortHandler} />
        </div>
        <div className="shop__main">
          <aside className="shop__sidebar">
            <ShopNavPlants />
          </aside>

          <div className="shop__products">
            {products.map((product) => {
              return <ProductOverview key={product.id} product={product} />;
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

In ShopNavPlants:

```
// TODO: REFACTOR FILTERING, ADD FILTERING HOOK?
const filterReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_FILTER": {
      const updatedState = [...state];
      updatedState.push(action.filter);

      return updatedState;
    }

    case "REMOVE_FILTER": {
      const updatedState = [...state].filter((name) => {
        return name !== action.filter;
      });

      return updatedState;
    }
    case "ACTIVE_FILTERS": {
      const updatedState = [...action.filterList];
      return updatedState;
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const ShopNavPlants = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [filterStates, dispatch] = useReducer(filterReducer, []);

  // Handles filterState change and pushes filters to query
  useEffect(() => {
    //  prevent error with debounce timer (too many url changes)
    const debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (!filterStates || filterStates.length === 0) {
        router.push({});
        return;
      }
      const filterQuery = filterStates.join("&");
      router.query.features = filterQuery;
      router.push({
        query: {
          ...router.query,
        },
      });
    }, 500);

    return () => clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
  }, [filterStates]); 
  
  // Handles any active filters on mount (refresh)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      if (router.query?.features) {
        dispatch({
          type: "ACTIVE_FILTERS",
          filterList: router.query.features.split("&"),
        });
      }
    }
  }, [router.isReady]);

  const checkboxHandler = (e) => {
    !e.target.checked
      ? dispatch({ type: "REMOVE_FILTER", filter: e.target.name })
      : dispatch({ type: "ADD_FILTER", filter: e.target.name });
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className="shop__sidebar__list-filter">
        <li className="shop__sidebar__item">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={checkboxHandler}
            name={"petFriendly"}
            checked={filterStates.includes("petFriendly") ? true : false}
          />
          Pet-Friendly
        </li>
        <li className="shop__sidebar__item">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={checkboxHandler}
            name={"lowLight"}
            checked={filterStates.includes("lowLight") ? true : false}
          />
          Low-Light
        </li>
        <li className="shop__sidebar__item">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={checkboxHandler}
            name={"lowMaintenance"}
            checked={filterStates.includes("lowMaintenance") ? true : false}
          />
          Low-Maintenance
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Any thoughts and advice on this?

Also, if I my data is received from getStaticProps on a database I created with mongoDb. At first I thought that the useEffect would "overwrite" my pre-rendered data but I was mistaken. But if I view my page source, everything seems to be rendered, so this doesn't seem to have any effects on the benefits of SEO does it? If anyone has insight on this, that would be helpful. Anyways, any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a cyclic dependency in your code, which is logically not clean, and could lead to an infinite loop, if you would add products to the dependencies array:

- `filteredItems` depends on `products` (`filteredItems = props.products.filter(...`), and
- `products` depends on `filteredItems` (`setProducts( sortProducts( filteredItems, ... ) )`)

In React, you need to understand which state depends on which other state (and what "depends on" means).

E.g. if `products` changes, then `filteredItems` necessarily must always change as well.

Your code probably only works because `products` is missing from the dependencies list, and the whole `useEffect` code is probably only called once, so the data is likely correct, but that is only "coincidence" (or a consequence of the way the code is arranged and executed), but it is not logically safe.

You should either:

- maintain *two* lists (full list and filtered list), or
- make sure the list will guaranteed only be filtered once (you do not want to filter the already filtered list again, i.e. `products` should not depend on `filteredItems`).

### other ideas for improvement

In case you would get rid of the "set-state" calls (i.e. `setProducts`) in the process of changing the code, it might make sense to use `useMemo` instead of `useEffect`, e.g. `const filteredItems = useMemo(() => { return products.filter( ... ) }, [ products ] )`.

You are calling `sortProducts( ... )` too many times, especially unnecessarily on every render inside the initial `useState( sortProducts( ... ) )`. You could put that in a e.g. `const sortedProducts = useMemo( products )`.

You could extract the whole `useRouter` and `toArray = router.query` stuff into a separate custom hook,